# root : problem with defaults entries

Tags: server, sudo, configuration

I'm getting security mail from my server saying: `root : problem with defaults entries ; TTY=unknown ; PWD=/root ; USER=root`

Upon browsing around, "they" say;

> This problem is caused by sudo looking for directives in a place it cannot find them: sss. Check the /etc/nsswitch.conf

and to modify the line

`sudoers:        files sss`

and remove the sss.
but I don't even have a line with sudoers?

should I add one?

don't want to mess with stuff I don't completely understand.

Answer (score 1):

Hi had the same problem when I was using sudo. I also didn't have the `sudoers: files sss` line in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`.

I would also get an additional email with the subject "`root : unable to resolve host my-server-hostname`"

I found by adding my server's hostname to `/etc/hosts` both emails stopped:

`127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain my-servers-hostname`

I hope this helps.